# How to declare nullable discriminated union?

Tags: f#

I have a discriminated union like this

```
type foo =
| Yes of bool
| Number of decimal
```

I have another type where I'm trying to delcare this DS as a nullable member

```
type test(value) =
member this.Value : Nullable<foo> = value
```

When I try to do that, I'm getting "A generic construct requires that the type "foo" have a public default constructor. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why nullable, and not an option? Is nullable a requirement here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.NET's `Nullable<T>` type is really designed to be used with value types such as `int` and not with reference types such as `string` as they are already nullable.

Discriminated unions are reference types by default as they are actually compiled to a class. But they can be forced to be a struct, which would make it a value type. However, when you do that you get another error: `If a union type has more than one case and is a struct, then all fields within the union type must be given unique names`. You can name the values inside each case as in this example:

```
[<Struct>]
type foo =
| Yes of yes:bool
| Number of number:decimal
```

Now you can have a `Nullable<foo>`. But you probably don't actually want to do this. The normal way in F# to represent a "nullable" value for both reference and value types is to use `Option` type. So instead of making `foo` a struct, you should probably change the type to `Option<foo>` instead:

```
type test(value) =
    member this.Value : Option<foo> = value

test(Some (Number 1M)) // some value
test(None) // no value
```

F# **largely** makes it impossible for types defined in F# to be null, so you would use `Option` for everything instead of making the distinction between reference and value types. `Nullable` is only really useful for working with existing .NET code that uses it.